# Breadcrumb menu PHP generating additional blank anchor links

Tags: php, html, breadcrumbs

Lets say I have the following URL:

```
https://site.website/products/products-level-2
```

And on `products-level-2` I have a breadcrumb hero section. What I'm expecting to see is:

`Products / Products Level 2`

However, with my current approach, I'm seeing:

`/ Products / Products Level 2 /`

^^ the above has the following HTML output:

```html
<!-- link 1 - not needed -->
<a class="crumbMenu" href="site.website"> </a>
<span class="slash">/</span> 

<!-- link 2 -->
<a class="crumbMenu" href="site.website//products">Products </a>
<span class="slash">/</span> 

<!-- link 3 -->
<a class="crumbMenu" href="site.website//products/products-level-2">Products Level 2</a>
<span class="slash">/</span>

<!-- link 4 - not needed -->
<a class="crumbMenu" href="site.website//products/products-level-2"> </a>
<span class="slash">/</span>
```

The above has the following issues:

1. It's outputting blank / not needed anchor links.
2. In the href, it's outputting double `//` (i.e. `site.website//products`)
3. I also do not want the last item (i.e `products level 2`) to be a link (since the user is viewing the breadcrumb on that page).
4. I don't want `/` to appear at the start and end of the breadcrumb.

**Here is my current approach:**

```
<?php
// 1. Get URL
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$address = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// 2. Strip extras
$build = '';
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    $build .= '/'.$crumb;
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
    echo
        "<a class='crumbMenu' href=".$address.$build.">".$crumb."</a> 
        <span class='slash'>/</span> ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

The final working code you end up with is as follows:

```
<?php
// 1. Get URL
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
array_filter($crumbs);

$count = count($crumbs);
$address = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// 2. Strip extras
$build = '';
$i = 0;

foreach($crumbs as $crumb) {

    $href = (++$i != $count ? 'href="' . $address . $build . '"' : '');

    $build .= '/'.$crumb;
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
    echo
        "<a class='crumbMenu' " . $href . ">".$crumb."</a> 
        <span class='slash'>/</span> ";
}
?>
```

### Explanation:

**1. It's outputting blank / not needed anchor links.**

Simply run array_filter, this will remove any blank elements in the array.

```
array_filter($crumbs);
```

**2. In the href, it's outputting double // (i.e. site.website//products)**

The reason this happens is because it iterates through the blank element in the array first and as this adds a forward slash by default, by the second loop there is already a forward slash present, so it doubles up.

This issue is solved in the solution to question 1.

**3. I also do not want the last item (i.e products level 2) to be a link (since the user is viewing the breadcrumb on that page).**

After running `array_filter` on `$crumbs` you'll want to count how many elements are in the array using:

```
$count = count($crumbs);
```

Then when you are looping through the array, you'll want to workout when the loop is the last loop of the array:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($crumbs as $crumb) {

    $href = (++$i != $count ? 'href="' . $address . $build . '"' : '');

    // ...rest of foreach
    $build .= '/' . $crumb;
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');

    echo "<a class='crumbMenu' " . $href . ">".$crumb."</a><span class='slash'>/</span> ";

}
```

**4. I don't want / to appear at the start and end of the breadcrumb.**

This was resolved with my solution to your first question right at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* A character used as a divider between the breadcrumbs */
$separator = ' / ';

/* The current page uri from which to build breadcrumb trail */
$uri='https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/products/computers/microsoft/laptops/acer/professional';

/* capture the path and explode to create an array - removing empty entries in the process */
$crumbs=array_filter( explode( '/', parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH ) ) );

/* The host and protocol for building correct links */
$host=sprintf( '%s://%s/', parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_SCHEME ), parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_HOST ) );

/* placeholder array to store generated links */
$html=[];

/* iterate through the array and build relevant HTML content - append to output array */
foreach( $crumbs as $index => $crumb ){
    /* tweak the text displayed */
    $crumb = ucfirst( str_replace( array( ".php", "_" ), array( "", " " ), $crumb ) );

    /* the path should be all the previous breadcrumb crumbs */
    $path=[];
    for( $i=1; $i < $index; $i++ ) $path[]=$crumbs[ $i ];
    $path=implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path );


    /* create the link used in the html display */
    $html[]= ( $index==count( $crumbs ) ) ? sprintf('<span>%s</span>', $crumb ) : sprintf("<a href='%s%s' class='crumbMenu'>%s</a>", $host, $path, $crumb );
}


echo $uri, "
<style>
    #breadcrumbs{border:1px solid gray;padding:1rem;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial}
    #breadcrumbs *{padding:1rem;}
    #breadcrumbs a,
    #breadcrumbs span:hover{color:blue}
    #breadcrumbs a:hover{color:red;}
    #breadcrumbs span{font-weight:bolder;}
</style>
<div id='breadcrumbs'>",
implode( $separator, $html ),
"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve 1,2,4 just remove the leading and trailing slashes. To solve 3 you need to make a simple if:

```
// 1. Get URL
$crumbs = explode("/", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/'));
$address = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// 2. Strip extras
$build = '';
$lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;

foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
    $build .= '/'.$crumb;
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');

    echo $key < $lastKey
        ? "<a class='crumbMenu' href=".$address.$build.">".$crumb."</a>
           <span class='slash'>/</span>"
        : $crumb;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/BqD7C